# update sequence value dynamically - plsql

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have a table with three columns **col_a,col_b** and **col_c**. col_a and **col_b** has values and **col_c** has null values. I just want to update the **col_c** with start sequence of **col_a** corresponding **col_b**. Expecting values of **col_c** is shown below. Using cursor to achieve this scenario.

```
COL_A       COL_B       COL_C

     1          1         1   
     2          1         2  
     3          1         3 
     4          1         4  
     5          1         5  
     6          1         6  
     7          1         7  
     8          1         8  
     9          1         9  
    10          1        10  
   101          2       101
   102          2       102
   104          2       103
   106          2       104
   107          2       105
   108          2       106
   110          2       107
   201          3       201
   202          3       202
   203          3       203
   204          3       204
   205          3       205
   301          5       301
   302          5       302
   305          5       303
   306          5       304
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use a correlated subquery which finds, for each `COL_B` set of records, the minimum `COL_A` value to start the sequence.  To this value we add the appropriate offset using `COUNT`.

```
UPDATE yourTable t1
SET COL_C = (SELECT MIN(t2.COL_A) +
                    COUNT(CASE WHEN t2.COL_A < t1.COL_A THEN 1 END)
             FROM yourTable t2
             WHERE t2.COL_B = t1.COL_B);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reponse sir. It reversely updating....                                            
  `SQL> UPDATE tmp123 t1
   SET COL_C = (SELECT MIN(t2.COL_A) +
                        COUNT(CASE WHEN t2.COL_A > t1.COL_A THEN 1 END)
                 FROM tmp123 t2
                 WHERE t2.COL_B = t1.COL_B);`

Comment: Please reload your page as I have updated my answer.

Comment: This update query working great. Shall i use it in plsql block using cursor?

Comment: I am not so familiar with cursors in Oracle.  The update should work standalone just as well.

Comment: Thanks for the help sir @Tim Biegeleisen learned a useful scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of the analytical function as following:

```
Merge into your_table t
Using
(Select col_a, col_b,
       First_value(col_a) over (partition by col_b order by col_a)
       + row_number() over (partition by col_b order by col_a) - 1 as col_c
   From your_table) S
On (t.col_a = s.col_a and t.col_b = s.col_b)
When matched then 
Update set t.col_c = s.col_c
```

Cheers!!